# Entity Framework Context on multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, entity-framework, unity-container

I've seen so many questions similar to mine, but no answers that quite seem to apply to my situation.

My ASP.NET MVC app with EF 6 Code first and Unity has a web service that adds something to the database, then fires off another thread that adds more stuff to the database.  The reason for using the other thread is to return the original request as quickly as possible.  The context class is obtained using the Unity container RegisterType().

I've got lots of repository classes all using the same context, so to make sure they get the same instance I could use the PerRequestLifetimeManager in my Unity container, and that's fine for the http request threads but that the other threads can't use the context returned by the PerRequestLifetimeManager because this is only valid on the original http request thread.

So, I can use the PerThreadLifetimeManager.  This is great because now the main request thread and the other thread it kicks off get the same instance of the context returned by Unity.  The trouble is that so do other requests if they get given the same thread, so this is no good either.

So how can I configure things so that the request threads get their own PerRequest Lifetime Manager created context, and other threads get a different context?

The issue is made a little more difficult by the fact that the new thread calls other classes that need to use a context instance.  However, these other classes can be used from the main request thread or the new thread, so grabbing a context instance when the thread is started and then passing it around will be tricky.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No takers then...

I'm going to have a go at answering my own question, but could do with some thoughts on my approach.

So I can't use the PerRequestLifetimeManager because worker threads can't use the context that this returns, but I can't use the PerThreadLifetimeManager because the context can last the lifetime of several HTTP requests.  This class attempts to provide the best of both worlds.

```
/// <summary>
/// For the context class the PerRequestLifetimeManager is the most suitable lifetime manager,
/// but this doesn't work when a new worker thread is started as this needs to access the context.
/// The PerThreadLifetimeManager is no good either as the context can last for more than on request.
/// This class attempts to give the best of both worlds: per request lifetime management for HTTP requests
/// and thread storage for worker threads.
/// </summary>
public class PerRequestOrThreadLifetimeManager : PerRequestLifetimeManager, IDisposable
{
    private const string threadDataSlotName = "PerRequestOrThreadLifetimeManager";

    public override object GetValue()
    {
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null)
        {
            return base.GetValue();
        }
        else
        {
            return getManagedObject();
        }
    }

    public override void RemoveValue()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void SetValue(object newValue)
    {
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null)
        {
            base.SetValue(newValue);
        }
        else
        {
            Thread.SetData(Thread.GetNamedDataSlot(threadDataSlotName), newValue);
        }
    }

    private object getManagedObject()
    {
        return Thread.GetData(Thread.GetNamedDataSlot(threadDataSlotName));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        try
        {
            IDisposable obj = getManagedObject() as IDisposable;
            if (obj != null)
            {
                obj.Dispose();
                obj = null;
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```